# Intellij Gradle dependsOn "Cannot resolve symbol"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have been trying to learn Gradle but intellij kept giving me warnings like Can not resolve symbol or can not infer argument type.
Here's my code

```
task hello << { print "hello"}
task world(dependsOn: hello) << { println "world"}
```

The code works fine but the `hello` in `dependsOn: hello` is marked by the warning **can not resolve symbol "hello"** and the the rest is marked by **can not infer argument types.**

Can someone explain to me how to fix the code?
Im running the latest version of gradle and intellij idea.

Comment: Adding the wrapper task to your build.gradle helps resolve some of those symbols. I guess gradle DSL support in intellij is still being worked on.